# Using .htaccess to redirect to specific off-site page

Tags: apache, .htaccess

When a server is down, one can access the Coral Cache of the site here:

```
http://someDomain.com.nyud.net/
```

Currently I send 500 errors for every page to the Coral Cache for the homepage like so:

```
ErrorDocument 503 http://someDomain.com.nyud.net/
```

However, I would like to use rewriting to send the user to the correct page:

```
http://someDomain.com/some/page.html <- Broken! Send user to:
http://someDomain.com.nyud.net/some/page.html
```

How can one accomplish this in .htaccess? I have found many rewrite examples for redirecting to different pages on the same server, but I have found nothing that will redirect a host only on a 500 error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like the ErrorDocument directive supports this.

Unless Coral Cache can pick up the HTTP referer before processing (you should get the original path from that), then you might have to force and external redirection to a resource on your server, that can then redirect to a resource on the Coral Cache, using the referer e.g:

```
ErrorDocument 503 http://someDomain.com/some/errorhandler

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://someDomain.com/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^some/errorhandler$ http://someDomain.com.nyud.net/%1 [L,NC]
```

Obviously this is not great and you might want to consider a different approach, such as creating a custom script that handles the Error (see guidelines below).

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/custom-error.html

Comment: Thanks. Obviously if the server is 500'ing then I won't be running another script!

Comment: Actually, depending on the error I might be able to run another script. Thank you!